# LockRecursionException in multiple threaded function

Tags: c#, multithreading, exception, readerwriterlockslim, readerwriterlock

I dont know how to describe it but I'm getting exception that schouldn't have a place when a code is good written. This exception is about issue with ReaderWriterLockSlim and it's LockRecursionException; it is appearing at "ScreenLocker.EnterReadLock();" line. Can't find problem with my code and description what to do or what might be wrong at internet, that's why i writting this question here and asking you all for help. This is code I have problem with:

```
public static List<Dictionary<int, int>> RunTasks(ScreenScanning ss)
    {
        var listOfTasks = new List<Task>();
        List<Dictionary<int, int>> PosXOfBlocksAndMeaningOfIt = new List<Dictionary<int, int>>();
        for (var i = 0; i <= BlocksOnYAxisOnScreen; i++)
        {
            ScreenLocker.EnterReadLock();
            var t = new Task(() =>
            {
                PosXOfBlocksAndMeaningOfIt.Add(ss.XAxysScan(PosYOfRowsToScan[i], Screen, ref ScreenLocker));
            });
            listOfTasks.Add(t);
        }
        Task.WaitAll(listOfTasks.ToArray());
        return PosXOfBlocksAndMeaningOfIt;
    }
```

and that are functions called by this method:

```
public Dictionary<int, int> XAxysScan(int posY, Bitmap screen, ref ReaderWriterLockSlim screenLocker)
    {
        screenLocker.ExitReadLock();
        Dictionary<int, int> partOfMainTable = new Dictionary<int, int>();
        partOfMainTable.Add(666, posY); //used in BotViewUpdate in DataToTableInterpreter
        for (int i = 0; i <= 1920; i++)
        {
            if (screen.GetPixel(i, posY) == ColorsInRow[0])
            {
                if (IsFarmable(posY, ColorsInRow, i, screen))
                {
                    partOfMainTable.Add(i, 1);
                }
            }
            else if (IsBackground(BackgroundColors, i, posY, screen))
            {
                partOfMainTable.Add(i, 0);
            }
            else
            {
                partOfMainTable.Add(i, 2);                
            }
        }
        return partOfMainTable;
    }
```

How can you see I'm releaseing lock right after entering XAxysScan function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can you see I'm releasing lock right after entering XAxysScan function.

The [`ReaderWriterLockSlim`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim?view=net-5.0) is a [synchronization object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/overview-of-synchronization-primitives) that allows multiple threads to read from a resource, but only allow 1 resource to write to it(ideally).

The reason why this is important is because the specific way that `ReaderWriterLockSlim` is implemented to achieve this effect, requires something called [Managed Thread Affinity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim?view=net-5.0#remarks), which basically means that whatever `Task` or Thread that called the `EnterReadLock()` must be the **same** `Task` or thread that calls `ExitReadLock();`.

When we look at the following, we can see you Have `RunTasks(ScreenScanning ss)` enter the lock, but you immediately start a new child `Task` and pass the `ReaderWriterLockSlim` as a reference to `XAxysScan()`.

```cs
ScreenLocker.EnterReadLock();
var t = new Task(() =>
{
    PosXOfBlocksAndMeaningOfIt.Add(ss.XAxysScan(PosYOfRowsToScan[i], Screen, ref ScreenLocker));
});
```

Only the same `Task` that enters a lock can be the one to release that lock. At least for synchronization objects like `ReaderWriterLockSlim` that use [Managed Thread Affinity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim?view=net-5.0#remarks).

Consider moving `EnterReadLock()` into the `XAxysScan()` method.

```cs
public Dictionary<int, int> XAxysScan(int posY, Bitmap screen, ref ReaderWriterLockSlim screenLocker)
{
    screenLocker.EnterReadLock();
    try{
        Dictionary<int, int> partOfMainTable = new Dictionary<int, int>();
    partOfMainTable.Add(666, posY); //used in BotViewUpdate in DataToTableInterpreter
        for (int i = 0; i <= 1920; i++)
        {
            if (screen.GetPixel(i, posY) == ColorsInRow[0])
            {
                if (IsFarmable(posY, ColorsInRow, i, screen))
                {
                    partOfMainTable.Add(i, 1);
                }
            }
            else if (IsBackground(BackgroundColors, i, posY, screen))
            {
                partOfMainTable.Add(i, 0);
            }
            else
            {
                partOfMainTable.Add(i, 2);                
            }
        }
        return partOfMainTable;
    }
    finally
    {
        // make sure that even if we encounter an error, we still exit the lock so other threads can enter the lock / begin writing
        screenLocker.ExitReadLock();
    }
```